# Create log instance when creating a new class in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

i have two impl packages (contains implementation for service/dao methods)
and i want when creating any new class in this package

the following line gets added to class by default (log instantiation):

```
Log log = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());
```

another thing is that i want when adding unimplemented method in the **impl package for dao** is to add the spring annotation

```
@Transactionl
```

any ideas how to accomplish those things in eclipse (i am using **Eclipse Helios 3.6**).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to have a specific template for a given package.

Some notes, though :

- the service layer should demarcate transactions. Not the DAO layer.
- you could inherit a base class with a protected log field, and all the subclasses would inherit it. Since you're calling initializing the log with `getClass()`, the actual subclass name would be used.
- Only public methods should be transactional. The other ones aren't intercepted by Spring, so their transactional annotation would be ignored anyway.
- if you want to have all the methods of a bean to be transactional, put the annotation on the class rather than each individual method.

Comment: can i add @Transactional on the whole class, or i have to add it for each method ? and what do you mean by point number 3.

Comment: Yes. You can put it on the whole class. My post was truncated du to a connection error. I edited it.